# How to detect if foreground service is running (Activity leaks Service)

Tags: android, android-service

My Activity starts a foreground service. I pause the Activity (by clicking Home, or removing it from the recent list) and the foreground service continues to run, which is the desired behaviour.

If I then restart my Activity (by clicking Apps->MyActivity) it seems to start a new foreground process, meaning that I then have two (or more) of the same process running. If I press Back to pause the Activity, I see an error in the logs that the process has been leaked.

```
The error:
Activity com.mypackage.foreground.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.mypackage.foreground.MainActivity$1@aa2d453 that was originally bound here
```

The question is, how can I ensure only one instance of the service exists? If I restart the Activity, how can I either leave the existing service running, or ensure the new one replaces the existing one?

Comment: you are calling `bindService` but you forgot about `unbindService` method

Comment: and no, a service is a singleton: no multiple instances of it

Comment: Well a) I don't want to unbind it - I want it to continue running. And b) I have proof in the logs that I can create 1, 2, more instances of it - I guess this is the 'leaked' process still performing its task.

Comment: a) [Binding to a started service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#bind-started-service) b) no it is no possible - when restarted the service has to be shut down first

Comment: your error says: `"[...] has leaked ServiceConnection"` - as you already know `ServiceConnection` is used for service binding - so you really have to call `unbindService` from your activity

Comment: Ok I see... but where would I call that, and when?

Comment: and where do you call `bindService`? as a thumb rule you should pick a correspomding method of life cycle of your activity

Comment: I was under the impression that calling unbind() would stop the service from running... but clearly I wasn't understanding the whole process properly. As I'm sure you would predict, when I unbind, the service continues running happily. When I restart the Activity, the service restarts. I get no dual processes, and no service leaks. I think I've learnt something today, thanks for the tips!

Comment: sure, your welcome